# save iron-form data to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, form-submit

I have this code and I want to use Firebase like a real time database, but is not working, could some one please help me, this is my code:

```
<paper-material elevation="1">
  <form is="iron-form" id="form">
    <paper-input label="name" id="nameform"></paper-input>
    <paper-checkbox id="checkboxform">i agree</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-radio-group selected="a" id="radioform">
      <paper-radio-button name="a">yes</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button name="b">No</paper-radio-button>
    </paper-radio-group>
    <paper-button on-click="_submit">Save</paper-button>
  </form>
</paper-material>
```

I already try to send element by element using

```
_submit: function(){    
var values = {
    Name: this.$.name.value,
    // all other values
    }
firebase.database().ref().push(values);
}
```

this example sends the info, but this is not working with the checkboxes an the radiogroups elements. 
Thats why Im tryin the send all the info in the form  with iron-form:

```
  listeners: {
    'form.iron-form-submit': '_handleFormSubmit'
  },

  _submit: function() {
    var formvalues= this.$.form.submit();
    console.log(formvalues);
    firebase.database().ref().push(formvalues);
  },

  _handleFormSubmit: function() {
    console.log('save it');
  }
```

console.log says "undefined"

thanks in advance